# Here's a light hearted question.. but comes with irritating answers lol

Tags: annoying

So what do you as an engineer in mixing recording track laying etc find extremely annoying.?.

For me : If ive been working on a film for a few weeks and nearing the end with the director and some little snot (usually clueless but to his world) comes in from the production team to watch some of what the movie is like and starts to through his 10cents around. "oh dont you think it would be better if you did this ...  " Maybe you could try this or less of that!!!

Hours of work then just to show him /her that they should rather shut their mouths and leave it to directors , producers and engineers .

Answer (score 1):

It's a little nit-picky, but I tend to leave all my tracks in touch/latch with everything enabled in the automation window. So when I'm working down the chain from someone who has turned off all the automation enables except for "mute" or "send pan" and it takes that extra 15 seconds of "what the ----? Did my control surface lose connection? Is the track not armed? Is the volume automation enabl... Ah-ha" I just don't get it.

Answer (score 1):

Haha, this is a dangerous question. A few of mine:

- When Pro Tools randomly switches back to latch solo. I don't know if it's something that's fixed in PT10, but i hate latch solo! That's what shift is for!
- When there's some uncleanable noise over a line...and the actor delivered it completely differently in every other take (and ADR isn't a possibility).
- A recent one of mine is popping in VO. I don't know if it's because i've been doing a crazy amount of VO/dubbing recently, but i'm even starting to hear people pop in real life...

Of course, we're all cool about everything that annoys us, right?

Comment: we smile and move on

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Bourne... that is very annoying: when they ask the opinion of someone completely clueless.

To me the most annoying is the lack of time. They want it perfect, and give you 1/10 of the time needed to make it right. Then they judge your work based on that...

I worked in some TV series 2 years ago, and I had 48 hours to produce/compose the music for 1 entire 40 min. show, produce the FX, dialog edit, and mixing. We were a team of 2... those were the worst 2 months of my entire life.

It was even worse, after delivering the audio they put some girl that did the WORST possible mastering you can imagine.